# Value present in [] inside iptables rules

Tags: iptables

After reading all articles I got that the number inside [:] means packet counter and bytes counter.

But what I did not understand and did not find anywhere is what the number means and important. I mean when 
I write [0:0] ---> what I came to know is that it will accept all data coming from any network.
When will I write [7752:8249066] what will happen?  Please clear me this and how I will decide which number to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this other Answer
[What do numbers in INPUT,FORWARD,OUTPUT chains mean in iptables config file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108171/what-do-numbers-in-input-forward-output-chains-mean-in-iptables-config-file) 
The Numbers in Brackets are Statistical Values that the Command `iptables-save` reads from the running Firewall representing the **Traffic** that has been filters by the Chain.

You cannot assign them your own Values for any desired Traffic Rates or Bandwidth.
Values like

```
*filter
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
```

simply mean that this Chain never had been used. Likely because it does not have any Rule.

Comment: It makes 100% sense now, Thanks for this clarity.